# How to short address in Google Autocomplete places API in android

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-places-autocomplete

Hey I am using google autocomplete places API in my application where user have to select their address now the problem is that it is showing a long address while i want a very short and specific address

**image to show the address
**
[image]

**i want it only "Ganesh Nagar, Bharatpur" not this much long address. How can i solve this issue please guide me**

i tried to solve this but not able. I want it to be precise only not this long address.

**CODE I AM USING**

```
  Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    }
    catch (Exception ioException) {
        Log.e("", "Error in getting address for the location");
    }
    if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
        msg = "No address found for the location";
        sendResultsToReceiver(1, msg);
    }
    else {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);

        String addressDetails =  address.getAddressLine(0);

        sendResultsToReceiver(2, addressDetails);
    }
```

Comment: You need to mail to google map this is paid API you can achive this by using that.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code and changes as per your requirements.

```
  List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
            String address1 = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
            String address2 = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you want to display city name then you can use that string and if you want state as well then append it. You can also get latitude and longitude.

**edit-** Still if you are getting a long address line at 0 indexing then use the following method call to get split string based on the comma.

**KOTLIN -**

```
fun getShortAddressLine(tag:String) : String{
    var splitString= tag?.split("[/,/]".toRegex())
    var arraysize= splitString.size

    return splitString[0]
}
```

**JAVA -**

```
 public static String getShortAddressLine(String tag) {
    Regex regex = new Regex("[/,/]");
    List splitString = regex.split(tag, 0);
    int arraysize = splitString.size();
    return (String)splitString.get(0);
}
```